# DIC implementation in R

Tags: r, mcmc, jags

I'm having trouble to implement deviance information criterion manually for a JAGS model

```
model = "
data{ 
  for(i in 1:n){
    zeros[i]<- 0
  }
}
model{
  C <- 10000
  for (i in 1:n) {
    zeros[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
    lambda[i] <- -l[i] + C
    l[i] <- 
      -0.5*log(sigma[i]*(y[i]*(1-y[i]))^3) + 
      -0.5*(1/sigma[i])*((y[i]-mu[i])^2)/(y[i]*(1-y[i])*mu[i]^2*(1-mu[i])^2)
    logit(mu[i]) <- beta0 + beta1*income[i] + beta2*person[i]
    log(sigma[i]) <- -delta0
  }
  Deviance <- -2*sum(l[])
  beta0 ~ dnorm(0,.001)
  beta1 ~ dnorm(0,.001)
  beta2 ~ dnorm(0,.001)
  delta0 ~ dnorm(0,.001)
}"
```

In `rjags` package there is a function called `dic.samples()` that return the DIC value, but the problem is that for this model with Poisson trick it doesn't work.

Here is what I want to implement [DIC code](https://gist.github.com/gaberoo/4619102#file-2-dic-r),but I don't know well how do that

**EDIT:**
If I run `coda.samples` and request monitoring the deviance node, it will return the posterior mean and standard deviation, then I can calulate DIC using Gelman approximation to pD. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

A related problem: I couldn't extract DIC from models fit with the 'R2jags' package - the dic.samples() and related functions did not work.

Also, because my model was simultaneously calculating a lot of derived parameters (my outcome variable over a fine-scale gradient of the predictor variable), I couldn't use the documented print() function, because there was too much text and it got truncated before the DIC output.

The solution took a bit of poking around in the output data structure but is very easy. If you you fit your model by:

```
    model.name <- jags(data=jag.data, inits=inits, parameters.to.save=parameters, model.file="modelfile.txt", n.thin=nt, n.chains=nc, n.burnin=nb, n.iter=ni, DIC=T, working.directory=getwd())
```

Then you can call the pD and DIC values via:

```
model.name$BUGSoutput$pD
model.name$BUGSoutput$DIC
```